# How to save an image with CSS filter applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, filter

I am wondering how I can apply a CSS filter to an image and then save the image to disk.

For example, I have an image tag, I can apply a sepia effect via CSS

```
img.sepia{
  filter: sepia(20%);
}
```

And apply the class to an image tag in the HTML

```
<img src="img.png" class="sepia" />
```

How can I save that image with the filter applied?

Comment: [Screen grab](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13776/windows-use-snipping-tool-to-capture-screenshots)

Comment: You can always take screenshots from screen if you are looking for your own use.

Comment: Nope, i basically wants to use it for my website. so if i upload a photo to website so i can apply filter on it by css and then save it to my gallery.

Comment: You cannot access the file system from JavaScript running in a browser.

Comment: Yes exactly you cannot save the images ... but, give user a prompt to save the image .. Use https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ to take screenshot of any size from the browser page. .

Answer (score 9):

You could write the image to a canvas element, set the filter you want in javascript and then download that. So it would be something like this

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('image');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.filter = "sepia(20%)";
var img = document.getElementById("dataimage");
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

var downloadFile = document.getElementById('download');
downloadFile.addEventListener('click', download, false);


function download() {
   var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
   this.href = dt;
};
```

```css
img{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}
```

```html
<img src="" id="dataimage" />
<canvas id="image" width="400px" height="400px"></canvas>
<a id="download">Download image</a>
```

Comment: Okay. thanks for the idea. i will learn canvas now. to solve this issue. but that download button didn't worked for me.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the browser compatibility before you choose the canvas method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter

It's not supported on most mobile browsers.

I use an image service like Cloudinary.