# How to download image with css overlay effects?

Tags: html, css

I have some images that I am using in my album. I create an image gallery using HTML and CSS. I changed the picture into black and white using a CSS effect.
Now I want to download the picture with CSS black and white effects but problem is that when I download it. It gives me the original image without CSS black and white.
Anyone can tell me how to download image after using CSS effects?

```
<style>
img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* convert image to black and white */
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
</style>

<p>Convert the image to black and white:</p>

<img src="pineapple.jpg" alt="Pineapple" width="300" height="300">
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39854891/how-to-save-an-image-with-css-filter-applied

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save an image with CSS filter applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39854891/how-to-save-an-image-with-css-filter-applied)

Comment: Thanks, sir for your response but here download is not working @TemporaryName

Comment: Exactly. It is not possible that easily. Easiest solution is shown in the linked post. @AssadYaqoob

Comment: ok thanks, sir I find a solution with your help

Answer (score 1):

This is the plugin that I make use of: [DOM to Image library](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image)

If you're using NPM:

```
npm install dom-to-image
```

then import,

```
import domtoimage from 'dom-to-image';
```

Sample HTML with markup that needs to be downloaded as image:

```
<div id="my-node">
    <img src="/assets/images/image.jpg"/>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn-primary" (click)="convertToPng()">Convert to PNG</button>
    <button class="btn-primary" (click)="convertToJpeg()">Convert to JPEG</button>
    <button class="btn-primary" (click)="downloadAsPng()">Download as PNG</button>
    <button class="btn-primary" (click)="downloadAsJpeg()">Download as JPEG</button>
</div>
```

Sample filters applied using CSS:

```
img {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
  }
```

**To Convert to PNG:**

```
convertToPng(){
    let node = document.getElementById('my-node');
    domtoimage.toPng(node)
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = dataUrl;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
    });
  }
```

**To Convert to JPEG:**

```
convertToJpeg(){
    let node = document.getElementById('my-node');
    domtoimage.toJpeg(node)
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = dataUrl;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
    });
  }
```

**To Download as  PNG:**

```
downloadAsPng(){
    let node = document.getElementById('my-node');
    domtoimage.toPng(node)
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = 'my-image-name.png';
        link.href = dataUrl;
        link.click();
    });
  }
```

**To Download as JPEG:**

```
 downloadAsJpeg(){
    let node = document.getElementById('my-node');
    domtoimage.toJpeg(node, { quality: 0.95 })
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = 'my-image-name.jpeg';
        link.href = dataUrl;
        link.click();
    });
  }
```

Comment: A great solution if one needs to download many images programmatically, but for just one or a few images, there's always Print-to-PDF.  Most browsers have an option to print as a PDF with all images/styling included, and from there its trivial to convert the PDF to whatever image format you may want.