# How to download image with color effect | mix-blend-mode: multiply;| -webkit-filter : hue-rotate(57deg); filter: hue-rotate(57deg);

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have an imp element representing .png image of T-Shirt. I want to download this image but can't download with color property. I need to change this color using css class with the help of js and php code.
Javascript function works fine. I am able to download image but not colored image.

Here's what I have now:

```
.imgCss{
    -webkit-filter : hue-rotate(57deg); 
    filter: invert(58%) sepia(36%) saturate(6773%) hue-rotate(57deg) brightness(90%) contrast(105%);
}


<div class="FinalProductImg" id="FinalProductImg">
    <div id="shirtDiv" class="page" style="width: 530px; height: 630px; position: relative; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"> 
        <img name="tshirtview" class="imgCss" id="tshirtFacing" src="img/crew_front.png"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download image with css overlay effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57747211/how-to-download-image-with-css-overlay-effects)

Comment: `img` elements do not have a `name` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use "html-to-image": https://github.com/bubkoo/html-to-image

Here's how you can achieve this using html/js:

```
<div id="my-node">
  <img src="" class="your-class" />
</div>
<script>
var node = document.getElementById("my-node");

htmlToImage
  .toPng(node)
  .then(function (dataUrl) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = dataUrl;
    //code to download the image here
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error("oops, something went wrong!", error);
  });
</script>
```